# Template Application for running Azure Custom Vision Image Detection not working once I open the application

Tags: android, android-studio

The template application I was using for running an image classifier model from Azure Custom Vision is not working when i try to build and run it first.

I tried building and running, as what the README.md said to test the application, but so far, i keep on getting errors that I hardly can even fathom. I expected this would run as said, but as I said, it kept on showing errors when I tried to open the app. The phone I'm using is a Huawei but I forgot the specific series and stuff. Here is the error log I got from just clicking on the app.

```
01/25 19:12:11: Launching 'app' on HUAWEI MED-LX9.
Install successfully finished in 5 s 540 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "demo.tensorflow.org.customvision_sample/demo.tensorflow.org.customvision_sample.ClassifierActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 9677 on device 'huawei-med_lx9-PEVBB20423201126'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/omvision_sampl: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
E/omvision_sampl: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
I/omvision_sampl: Reinit property: dalvik.vm.checkjni= false
I/omvision_sampl: ReInitProperties: persist.vm.debug.dumpapi= false
D/ActivityThread: Attach thread to application
D/HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory: HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory in.
I/HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory: add HwFrameworkSecurityPartsFactory to memory.
E/BehaviorCollectManager: Fail to acquire dataAnalyzerService...
I/omvision_sampl: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/omvision_sampl: QarthPatchMonintor::Init
I/omvision_sampl: 
I/omvision_sampl: QarthPatchMonintor::StartWatch
I/omvision_sampl: 
I/omvision_sampl: QarthPatchMonintor::WatchPackage: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/
I/omvision_sampl: 
I/omvision_sampl: QarthPatchMonintor::CheckAndWatchPatch: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/demo.tensorflow.org.customvision_sample
I/omvision_sampl: 
I/omvision_sampl: QarthPatchMonintor::CheckAndWatchPatch: /data/hotpatch/fwkhotpatch/all
I/omvision_sampl: 
I/omvision_sampl: QarthPatchMonintor::Run
I/omvision_sampl: 
I/omvision_sampl: QarthPatchMonintor::Reading
I/omvision_sampl: 
I/omvision_sampl: QarthPatchMonintor::CheckNotifyEvent
I/omvision_sampl: 
I/omvision_sampl: QarthPatchMonintor::CheckNotifyEvent before read
I/omvision_sampl: 
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=demo.tensorflow.org.customvision_sample#10169#256
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: need clear apicache,because volumes changed,oldCnt=0 newCnt=1
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=demo.tensorflow.org.customvision_sample#10169#0
I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: need clear apicache,because volumes changed,oldCnt=1 newCnt=1
I/AwareBitmapCacher: init processName:demo.tensorflow.org.customvision_sample pid=9677 uid=10169
E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@be12549
I/iGraphics: [0020080c] pn: demo.tensorflow.org.customvision_sample, p: 9677
I/iGraphics: [0030050c] PV 10
I/iGraphics: [0030050c] no element 'igfx'
I/iGraphics: [0030050c] LoadCloudParams lib file success.
E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
V/ActivityThread: callActivityOnCreate
D/tensorflow: CameraActivity: onCreate demo.tensorflow.org.customvision_sample.ClassifierActivity@f8dcd05
V/HwWidgetFactory: : successes to get AllImpl object and return....
I/DecorView[]:  old windowMode:0 new windoMode:1
I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
I/tensorflow: CameraActivity: Camera API lv2?: true
I/InterpreterApi: Loaded native library: tensorflowlite_jni
I/InterpreterApi: Didn't load native library: tensorflowlite_jni_gms_client
I/tflite: Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.hardware.chipname"
W/omvision_sample: type=1400 audit(0.0:6423): avc: denied { read } for pid=9677 name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=14884 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
I/tflite: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
I/tflite: Replacing 39 node(s) with delegate (TfLiteXNNPackDelegate) node, yielding 1 partitions.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
I/QarthLog: [PatchStore] createDisableExceptionQarthFile
I/QarthLog: [PatchStore] create disable file for demo.tensorflow.org.customvision_sample uid is 10169
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: demo.tensorflow.org.customvision_sample, PID: 9677
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{demo.tensorflow.org.customvision_sample/demo.tensorflow.org.customvision_sample.ClassifierActivity}: ai.customvision.visionskills.VisionSkillsException: {"NativeRuntimeError":"Skill[Classifier] Build Exception <JNIWrapperException: Failed to load model; Model name = <sample-tflite.cvmodel/cvexport.manifest>; details: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor, but class was expected (declaration of 'org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor' appears in /data/app/demo.tensorflow.org.customvision_sample-ujz1FIumEghqzxaDGOhliw==/base.apk)>"}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3897)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4076)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2473)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8349)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
     Caused by: ai.customvision.visionskills.VisionSkillsException: {"NativeRuntimeError":"Skill[Classifier] Build Exception <JNIWrapperException: Failed to load model; Model name = <sample-tflite.cvmodel/cvexport.manifest>; details: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor, but class was expected (declaration of 'org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor' appears in /data/app/demo.tensorflow.org.customvision_sample-ujz1FIumEghqzxaDGOhliw==/base.apk)>"}
        at ai.customvision.visionskills.VisionSkillsManager.throwIfJNIFailed(VisionSkillsManager.java:24)
        at ai.customvision.visionskills.VisionSkillsManager.SkillConfigurationBuild_orThrow(VisionSkillsManager.java:553)
        at ai.customvision.visionskills.VisionSkillsManager.skillConfigurationBuild(VisionSkillsManager.java:309)
        at ai.customvision.visionskills.ConfigurationBase.build(ConfigurationBase.java:41)
        at ai.customvision.visionskills.CVSClassifier$Configuration.build(CVSClassifier.java:64)
        at demo.tensorflow.org.customvision_sample.MSCognitiveServicesCustomVisionClassifier.<init>(MSCognitiveServicesCustomVisionClassifier.java:51)
        at demo.tensorflow.org.customvision_sample.ClassifierActivity.onCreate(ClassifierActivity.java:54)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8085)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8073)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1320)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3870)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4076) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2473) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8349) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
```